# Component always move a little more than I expected

Tags: flutter, flame

Hallo here is my code for a SpriteComponent, which starts outside of screen and should move into the screen after I trigger it.

```
@override
  void update(double dt) {
    if (gameRef.shouldMoveCharacter) {
      if (position.x < 0) {
        position += velocity * dt;
        acceleration++;
        velocity.x = velocity.x + acceleration;
      }
    super.update(dt);
  }
}
```

But this component will always move a little more right, which makes a small gaps between them as the screenshot[image] I assumed that the last `velocity.x` is too big that let Component run too much, But considered of different size of phone, how to solve this problem? Also I try to achieve a easyOut effect, but have no idea how to do that, since I am using the old version, so there is no MoveEffect T T. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of Flame are you using? We've had the MoveEffect for several years, but with different effect systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `velocity * dt` can bring position to be larger than 0 you'll have to clamp the position. I'm guessing that your anchor is `topLeft`, then you can just add this to the end of your if:

```dart
import dart:math;

...

position.x = min(position.x, 0);
```

Comment: Hi Spydon, thanks for the tips, I do not know clamp method:) Now I have tried to update my code, since I was learning flame with a very old tutorial with very old flame version